# server not sending custom header values

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm using PHP 5.2.17 to get a remote page, the HTTP requests contains some cookie values but cookies are not delivered to the destination page.

```
$url = 'http://somesite.com/';
$opts = array(
    'http' => array
        (
        'header' => array("Cookie: field1=value1; field2=value2\r\n")
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Can you help me find the problem?
Note: I can't use curl.
Thanks.

Comment: I think it may be because of some PHP or Apache settings, but I have no idea where...

Comment: Check `allow_url_fopen` like I was saying.  If that is disabled you can accomplish the task by using socket i/o.  Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) for examples, search the page for 'fsockopen-based HTTP request'.

Comment: The result of ini_get('allow_url_fopen') is "1".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `allow_url_fopen` is not enabled, check the value w/ ini_get: `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')`;

You might also do a sanity check by calling file_get_contents() on any old page you know is publicly accessible.

Other than that your example code looks just fine.

**Second Option, Socket Connection:**

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("somesite.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: somesite.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Cookie: field1=value1; field2=value2; path=/; domain=somesite.com;\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I used phpinfo(); it says Local Value and master Value  are "On".

Comment: Not running the script from the cli are you?

Comment: Sorry, what is cli? the PHP script is running on server, It works great on localhost, but when I upload it on server the cookies are not sent.

Comment: Are you sure you can make HTTP requests _from_ the server?  It's unusual, but sometimes servers are locked down such that requests out are restricted.

Comment: Yes! the above script echoes page content.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the receiving code is working properly?

I can get your example to work with the receiving page simply echoing:

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['field1'] . '::' . $_COOKIE['field2']; // returns value1::value2
?>
```

Alternatively, the site could be requiring a user agent (anything). I had this problem earlier in reaching Wikipedia (not restricted by all Mediawiki software; apparently just for the Wikimedia sites). Set the user_agent property inside the 'http' array to whatever value you want. (However, if you do happen to be trying to reach Wikipedia, you might instead try their api.php: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php ; if another Mediawiki site, use the same relative path)

Comment: receiving code is correct and aloso I used some header checking tool like http://www.ericgiguere.com/tools/http-header-viewer.html but no success.

Comment: So the receiving end is your site and software then, so the missing user agent could not be a problem?

Comment: I can set user agent ini_set('user_agent',"test agent");. there is no problem in setting user agent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://somesite.com/';
$opts = array(
    'http' => array
    (
        'header' => "Cookie: field1=value1; field2=value2\r\n"
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```